# creating event control in vb.net. Multiple controls with the same ID '1' were found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, event-handling

Im trying to create buttons on page load and have event controls to those. Im able to create the buttons but the event doesnt seem to be triggered when the button is clicked instead it throws an error stating multiple controls with id found.I think this has something to do with postback and unique ID creation for the buttons. can some one point me as to what to be added along with this?

```
 Sub createbutton()

        Dim but As New Button
        but.Text = "save"
        but.ID = "but"
        AddHandler but.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
        Me.form1.Controls.Add(but)

    End Sub
```

The event control for this is as below.

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        ' Handle your Button clicks here
        MsgBox("done")
    End Sub
```

Im getting the error

```
Multiple controls with the same ID '1' were found
```

The subroutine createbutton works on page load as follows.

```
Public Class Default3

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load ' to gen page on load ;)
    createbutton()

End Sub
```

Help is appreciated , Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are a guy who worked a lot with VB 6.0 
Control array feature is available in VB 6.0

in VB.net everything is depend upon control ID.

if you don't have specific requirement like ID should be same then i suggest pls append prefix and incremental ID would resolve your issue.

Let me know if you have some specific requirements

Thanks
Asif

**Corrected Code, Instead of ID it's name which allow uniqueness**

```
Public Class Form1   
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' Handle your Button clicks here
    MsgBox("done")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    createbutton()
End Sub
Sub createbutton()

    Dim but As New Button
    but.Text = "save"
    but.Name = "but"
    AddHandler but.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(but)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I tried initializing a counter and incrementing it everytime the subroutine is called. but still i get the same error. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer hope that resolve your query. Please mark if as answer if it works thanks :)